# Connection problems - Celery/Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, rabbitmq, celery

long night... can't get my second Celery/RabbitMQ setup run to work.

#### step 1

```
sudo rabbitmq-server
```

runs: **ok!**

#### step 2

```
python manage.py celeryd -l info
```

error: `[2010-12-28 03:38:24,690: ERROR/MainProcess] CarrotListener: Connection Error: Socket closed. Trying again in 28 seconds...`

---

I have definitely:

- added rabbitmq user and vhost
- updated the Django setings.py

---

### Edit:

I think it might have to with installing from a .deb instead of apt-get.

After uninstalling the deb and installing the apt-get version I get this:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

### My Solution:

> apt-get --purge remove rabbitmq-server
>
> apt-get install rabbitmq-server

...no comment...maybe need some sleep :)

---

Any ideas on how I could debug this? :|

Comment: You added a vhost and user, did you set permissions? `sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p <vhost> <user> ".*" ".*" ".*"`

Comment: I had the same issue too. You're solution of simply purging and then reinstalling worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the different versions of RabbitMQ that you're using, newer versions have new features and may be incompatible with Celery.  I've got the latest 2.3.1 version on my machine, installed from the RabbitMQ deb, this works OK unless you need to use SSL in which case you have to install a more recent version of Erlang/OTP, which is painful.

Also, it's probably better to use the init script to start the broker:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
```

If you start the broker from the init script you should be able to look at the broker error logs if the problem persists:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/rabbit@<your-local-host>.log
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I did faced this issue while installing rabbitmq-server, while i was installing chef.
The work around for me and the solution to this problem is given as follows.

```
    $ sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Then add.

```
    127.0.0.1 <hostname>
```

Here  is your hostname, if not sure about the hostname then run the following command:

```
    $ hostname
```

the Result is your hostname. Just add that to your /etc/hosts and then run:

```
    $ sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

And it was started.:)
This worked for me.
Thanks for your time to read.:)